# How to add mongo commands to PATH on Mac OSX

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDb 2.6.1 following the material from https://university.mongodb.com/ (great material by the way) but I am not being able to add to my path the mongo commands.

I've followed this guide http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/ and I modified my .bashrc like this

```
export PATH=/Users/jonathancaballero/bin/mongodb/mongodb_2.6.1/bin:$PATH
```

And there is indeed where the binaries are (checked using the finder directly)

**So my question is why I am not able to use mongod from any location in my terminal?**

Comment: It needs to be a single line in `.bash_profile`, iirc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please put the `PATH` export into `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/path/to/your/mongo/bin:$PATH
```

Edit: The reason to put it into `.bash_profile` is that this file will usually get executed when bash is started as a login shell while `.bashrc` usually is exectuted for interactive non-login-shells. What usually happens is that `.bashrc` gets sourced in  `.bash_profile`. This does not seem to be the case here. On MacOS X when you start a Terminal, `.bashrc` does not get executed. God knows why, as the shell opened should be an interactive non-login shell and therefor *should* execute `.bashrc`.

Another, albeit more "intrusive" solution would be to add the following to `.bash_profile`.

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

For those who are interested in the details: take a look into the according sections of [bash's manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Comment: There is still the question of "why was it necessary to modify .bash_profile instead of .bashrc" but it did solved the problem.

Comment: what would you do for the zsh shell? Markus W Mahlberg

Comment: @pixel67 same thing. The only change would be, instead of `.bashrc` write `.zshrc`.