# Export and import MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I would like to export one Mongo database to another.

But when I run:
`mongodump -h ds1sdf4.mlab.com:57064 -d heroku_randomkey -u myuser -p mypassword -o volumes/testdump/mongodb1`
Terminal tells me: `-bash: mongodump: command not found`

Am I doing this all wrong?

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: did you install mongo?

Comment: If you have mongo installed, that command should at least see `mongodump` being available.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306398/how-to-add-mongo-commands-to-path-on-mac-osx add your mongodump to your path variable

Comment: @AshokPatidar I am using macOS Mojave

Comment: @RisingSun No, I have not installed anything on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `mongo` on your system. `mongodump` is a part of that package. do `brew install mongo` and try your command again. If you do not have Brew, I suggest you install it from [here](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: I'm getting closer :) Now I´m getting: `Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.` I'm sure the password is correct, and the user I recon is correct as well..

Comment: since you just installed mongo, there is no user and password. This question will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921414/mongodb-what-are-the-default-user-and-password